# docker-compose scales starts more containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using the below command to scale my docker container using the docker-compose. When I enter the desired number, even though the desired number of containers are running, it creates more containers. Shouldn't it create the exact number that is desired and not spin up more containers?

```
docker-compose -p some-service up -d --scale some_service1=7
```

Interestingly, when I run the same command for a second time, it stops all the newly created containers and brings it back to 7. I noticed that because I have set that command up on a cron schedule which runs every hour.

The docker-compose.yml file has nothing but the the below lines of code:

```
version: '3'
services:
  some-service1:
    image: private_registry/service1_image
    environment:
      - SOME_NAME=key1
  some-service2:
    image: private_registry/service2_image
    environment:
      - SOME_OTHER_NAME=key2
```

Am I doing it wrong somewhere? or is it a bug in docker-compose?

Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40

docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471

Answer (score 0):

The `-p` option sets the project name. This must match previous runs to scale that same project. If it does not match, a new project will be created with the new prefix, and scaled independently.

Comment: Well, I thought of that. But the project name is the same. I even verified it with the name of the container docker-compose generates project-name_service -name_#. That doesn't seem to be the case as the second run of the same command spins down those newly created containers which it should not if it were a different project.

Comment: Please update your question with output from `docker ps` before and after, along with the scale command you've run.

Comment: I verified it with the `docker ps -a | grep 'project-name_service-name'` command. Says 14 containers instead of 7 - after two runs of the command (ran twice with an hour between them).